# Visualforce email template with User chosen criteria

Tags: visualforce-template

Is there any workaround to pass some User chosen data into VF Email templates for the controller to process?  I want the User to be able to choose a date range to send information about a collection of objects chosen by the User.  Is this possible?

EDIT:  In my scenario, the User will choose the date in the VF page.

```
public class VFTemplateController
{
    public Date userDate{get; set;}

    public VFTemplateController()
    {
        //How can I assign userDate to a value that a User could have chosen on a previous page for this email template?

    }
}
```

Comment: I think for a collection of custom selected records with no common parent, you will need to write an `Apex` utility for this sort of functionality.

Comment: You can use Custom Controllers for your Visualforce Email Template so you probably can write your logic to execute any particular actions. [check this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_with_apex.htm)

Comment: Well, records share a parent but we only want specific ones by User entered criteria they specify over date.

Comment: can you describe how do you see entire process? where user should enter that data or where should be that stored?

Comment: @kurunve It shouldn't matter where the User enters the data, but I added it to the question.  I'm asking how to feed User data into a VF Email template to dynamically fetch a set of child records.

Comment: u can use getters and vf template controller to get data based on current user as needed, process it and output in vf template. Template itself should be custom component with some input data. Issue is that sometimes emails are being send from default workflow users -- you need to catch that

Comment: @kurunve When I say 'User data' I mean data that the User chooses/enters.  Not actual data from the User object.

Comment: just saw upd, sorry. There is no way how to send data directly, you need to store them somewhere and requery during email sending process